# roscd to sandbox does not work

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps a stupid question. But roscd sandbox does not work "roscd: No such package/stack 'sandbox'". While it is in the package path and rosws lists it as well..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49018/roscd-to-sandbox-does-not-work../) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The directory `sandbox` is not a ROS package or stack, i.e. it neither contains a stack.xml nor a manifest.xml. `roscd` only knows about directories that contain these files.

Note that you cannot nest stacks in stacks or packages in packages.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-11-24**:
That seems logical. Then there is a however a mistake on the following tutorial page, where they use roscd to get to the sandbox. http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-24**:
True. Unfortunately, the tutorials are not always correct. But feel free to fix it.